# DB2 With Clause

Tags: sql, db2, common-table-expression

I am new to DB2 and I have a question about the **with** clause.
For example in the following query:

```
WITH values AS 
   (
      SELECT user_id, user_data FROM USER WHERE user_age < 20
   )       
SELECT avg(values.user_data) FROM values
UNION
SELECT sum(values.user_data) FROM values
```

How many times will the common table expression be executed? Will the result of the with clause be stored in a temporary table or it will do sub-select twice.
(I use with and union here just to give an example, and sorry for my poor english)

Comment: execute it and look at the plan, in [tag:sql-server] this will be executed twice.

Answer (score 1):

As @Vladimir Oselsky has mentioned, only looking at the execution plan will give you a definite answer. In this contrived example the CTE subselect will likely run twice.

Answer (score 0):

In DB2, common table expressions should create the Common Table Expression Node in the execution plan (see the documentation [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2tools.oe.doc.ug/osc_commontableexpressionnode.htm)).  This node explicitly says:

> They serve as intermediate tables. Traditionally, a nested table
>   expression also serves this purpose. However, a common table
>   expression can be referenced multiple times after it is instantiated;
>   nested table expressions cannot.

I read this as saying that the CTE is only evaluated once, instantiated, and then used multiple times.  Also, if the CTE is referenced only one time, the "instantiation" is optimized away.

Note that this is the way that Postgres handles CTEs (materialized subqueries) and not the way the SQL Server handles them.

Comment: This answer is specific to DB2 for z/OS, for the sake of completeness.

Comment: in dashDB, which is DB2-like, the table is being scanned multiple times.